# How to run multiple neo4j instances on ecs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, neo4j

How to run two instances of neo4j on EC2 Container Service.

I created two task definitions to run neo4j on 7474 and 7475. 
But both neo4j instances use same 7687 to provide data.

It works fine with one instance. How to make the second instance available separately?

Note: I have only one instance in my cluster.

Answer (score 0):

`neo4j` uses per default port `7687` for [bolt protocol](http://boltprotocol.org/).

The `listen` address and port can be configured with the [dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/connectors/) parameter:

```
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7000
```

The `advertised_address` can be configured with the [dbms.connector.bolt.advertised_address](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/connectors/)  parameter:

```
dbms.connector.bolt.advertised_address=<server-name>:9000
```

Comment: that sounds great. how to change this in docker container or ecs task?